# ORA-38104 - What is workaround to updating column in ON clause in a MERGE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c

I have `table FOO` with some ID values in `col N_RA_ID` for `MANUAL%` values in `col V_CUST_NUMBER` and some matching values in `col N_RA_ID` for NON-MANUAL values in `col V_CUST_NUMBER`. Here is sample data -

[image: TABLE FOO]

I want to self join on `col N_RA_ID` and wherever there is exact match, I want to `update N_RA_ID` to `null WHERE V_CUST_NUMBER LIKE 'MANUAL%'`

so the output should look like -

[image: Output]

I tried using a merge but got ORA-38104. Can anybody please help?

```
MERGE INTO FOO X 
USING  (
SELECT T1.V_CUST_NUMBER AS MAN_CUST,T1.N_RA_ID, T2.V_CUST_NUMBER
FROM FOO T1
JOIN FOO T2
ON T1.N_RA_ID = T2.N_RA_ID
AND UPPER(T1.V_CUST_NUMBER) NOT LIKE 'MANUAL%'

) Z
ON (X.N_RA_ID = Z.N_RA_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET X.N_RA_ID = null
WHERE UPPER(X.V_CUST_NUMBER) LIKE 'MANUAL%'


SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "X"."N_RA_ID"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause
*Action:
```

Comment: What do you mean by exact match? Can you share query that you tried using merge

Comment: @ikram - By exact match, I meant wherever `N_RA_ID` self joins. I have added the `MERGE` statement I had ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple update with an `exists ()` check:

```
update foo f1
set n_ra_id = null
where v_cust_number like 'MANUAL%'
and exists (
  select *
  from foo f2
  where f2.n_ra_id = f1.n_ra_id
  and v_cust_number not like 'MANUAL%'
);
```

The main update filters first on all rows starting with 'MANUAL', and the subquery inside the `exists()` looks for any row in the table with the same ID, but which does not start with 'MANUAL'. If there is no such non-manual row then that clause is false and the manual row is left untouched; if there is a match then the row is updated.

Demo:

```
select * from foo;

V_CUST_NU    N_RA_ID
--------- ----------
MANUAL033      17024
MANUAL034     589469
MANUAL035     589470
MANUAL036     589478
BHASAD        589478

update foo f1
set n_ra_id = null
where v_cust_number like 'MANUAL%'
and exists (
  select *
  from foo f2
  where f2.n_ra_id = f1.n_ra_id
  and v_cust_number not like 'MANUAL%'
);

1 row updated.

select * from foo;

V_CUST_NU    N_RA_ID
--------- ----------
MANUAL033      17024
MANUAL034     589469
MANUAL035     589470
MANUAL036           
BHASAD        589478
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual workaround is to select `T2.ROWID as RID` in the `USING` clause, and then instead of matching on `N_RA_ID` you match `ON X.ROWID = Z.RID`.

Like so:

```
MERGE INTO FOO X 
USING  (
SELECT T2.ROWID AS RID,           -- ADD THIS HERE
       T1.V_CUST_NUMBER AS MAN_CUST,T1.N_RA_ID, T2.V_CUST_NUMBER
FROM FOO T1
JOIN FOO T2
ON T1.N_RA_ID = T2.N_RA_ID
AND UPPER(T1.V_CUST_NUMBER) NOT LIKE 'MANUAL%'   
) Z
ON (X.ROWID = Z.RID)              -- CHANGE THE "ON" CLAUSE LIKE THIS
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET X.N_RA_ID = null
WHERE UPPER(X.V_CUST_NUMBER) LIKE 'MANUAL%'
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be workaround. I have a question, when you apply this condition `ON (X.ROWID = Z.RID) `, does it return both `MANUAL` and `NON MANUAL` rows up to that point? And then we go ahead and update the row which is `MANUAL%`? Is that right?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi - Correct. In addition, you don't really need to select ANYTHING in `Z` (the view in the `USING` clause) *other than* `T2.ROWID as RID`, since you are not really using any other bit of data from the table - all you need is the simple fact that a match is found. (Which is why the `UPDATE` with a semi-join condition works, as shown by Alex Poole.) The workaround shown here is more general though, it works in other applications of `MERGE`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle 18c, there exist some workarounds that can be applied to such `MERGE` statements, [which outsmart the parser who checks for ORA-38104 preconditions](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/02/how-to-work-around-ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated/). For example, you could use row value expressions with an additional dummy column comparison:

```
MERGE INTO FOO X 
USING  (
  SELECT T1.V_CUST_NUMBER AS MAN_CUST,T1.N_RA_ID, T2.V_CUST_NUMBER
  FROM FOO T1
  JOIN FOO T2
  ON T1.N_RA_ID = T2.N_RA_ID
  AND UPPER(T1.V_CUST_NUMBER) NOT LIKE 'MANUAL%'
) Z
ON ((X.N_RA_ID, 'dummy') = ((Z.N_RA_ID, 'dummy')))
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET X.N_RA_ID = null
WHERE UPPER(X.V_CUST_NUMBER) LIKE 'MANUAL%'
```